# JSON Web API.. No response in when getting consumed in PHP

Tags: php, json, node.js, web-services

I configured a Node.js server which pulls data from a PostgreSQL database and returns the response in the form of JSON.

The URL is:

```
http://139.59.232.218:3000/odoo-client?client_req={"opts" : {"login" : "admin","password" : "admin","db" : "cctv_prod_db","host": "139.59.232.218","port": "80"},"moduleDetail" : {"model" : "product.category","method" : "search","args" :[],"filter" : ["sub_category_type","ilike","service"],"fields" : "","domain" : "","offset" : "","limit" : "","sort" : "","resource_id":""}}
```

While it successfully returns the response when I load it in a web browser, when I try to consume it in PHP no response is returned.

This is my php:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Are you URL encoding that URL in PHP?

Comment: I just called it in PHP with the above code

Comment: Well maybe try URL encoding it, because at the moment it's not a valid URL.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the JSON string as a query parameter isn't a valid url string. You'll need to url-encode it:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://139.59.232.218:3000/odoo-client?client_req='.urlencode('{"opts" : {"login" : "admin","password" : "admin","db" : "cctv_prod_db","host": "139.59.232.218","port": "80"},"moduleDetail" : {"model" : "product.category","method" : "search","args" :[],"filter" : ["sub_category_type","ilike","service"],"fields" : "","domain" : "","offset" : "","limit" : "","sort" : "","resource_id":""}}');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;

?>
```

That said, since you're *sending* data to the server, you'd be far better off (and it would be more RESTful) to set this up as a [POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16920588/1214800) instead of a GET.

Comment: when i try to run the same code on live website instead of localhost it doesn't run.

Comment: "*   Trying 139.59.232.218...
* Immediate connect fail for 139.59.232.218: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0"

Comment: I am able to get the response if i hit it on a web browser

Comment: Might be something funky with your php setup? I got that from a random online php code runner.