# how can I send request in JSON format to POST data

Tags: php, json

I've a Api endpoint to work with code

```
<?php

    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];
    $gender= $_POST['gender'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "qwerty", "db");
    $query= mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(name,email, password, gender) VALUES('$name','$email', '$password', '$gender')");

    if($query){
        echo "You are sucessfully Registered";
    }

    else{
        echo "your details could not be registered";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

how can I make the request should look like

```
{ 
   "name":"abc", 
   "email":"gmail", 
   "gender":"male" 
}
```

I'm new to php Api development

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST request with JSON body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920291/post-request-with-json-body)

Comment: insert values to an array and use json_encode an array in php

Answer (score 2):

You have to build an array like so:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password']
);
```

And then you have to encode it : `$encoded = json_encode($data)`

Comment: This is not an answer, because there's no context.

Comment: Does it look like the OP provides a context? Not really. He asked how to get a JSON array, that's what I answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
    'userID'      => 'a7664093-502e-4d2b-bf30-25a2b26d6021',
    'itemKind'    => 0,
    'value'       => 1,
    'description' => 'Boa saudaÁ„o.',
    'itemID'      => '03e76d0a-8bab-11e0-8250-000c29b481aa'
);

$json = json_encode($data);

$client = new Zend_Http_Client($uri);
$client->setRawData($json, 'application/json')->request('POST');
```

using this method you can send request in post