# Why I can't get data use $_POST

Tags: php

I am develop a php data interface. But I can't get the data.

**A.php**

```
$options = [
       'http' => [
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $data,
            'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                         "Accept: application/json\r\n"
        ]
    ];
    $context  = stream_context_create( $options );
    $result   = file_get_contents('B.php', false, $context );
    echo $result; //Output: I have recvieve it. // It's proves that the url is right.
```

**B.php**

```
$data = $_POST; // The $data is empty. Why??? It can't get the data
echo 'I have recvieve it';
```

Comment: What is `$data` in A?

Comment: You're also doing `print_r($data)` or something to prove the data is empty…?

Comment: That's why: `Content-Type: application/json` http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php: _"An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method **when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type** in the request."_

Comment: If you really want to POST a **JSON** body, you have to use another API, e.g. **[curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920291/post-request-with-json-body)**.

Comment: I think i has found the reason. There are not only one way to get API data. Base the answer by CBroe. I use the $data = file_get_contents('php://input', 'r');