# Sending a post request with parameters in php to get Json data

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get some json data from another server that needs 3 parameters so that I can access it. I saw this code in internet but its not working. I have searched a lot and I haven't found a solution. When I run this code I get :

> use pass and code are missing

(is the response from the server I'm requesting), I hope I made things clear if there's anything I didn't explain please do tell.

```
    $url = 'http://xxxx/.js';
    $data =http_build_query(array('user' => 'xx',
            'pass' =>'xxx ',
               'code' =>'xxx')
  );


    $options = array(
   'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => $data
    )  
    );
     $context= stream_context_create($options);
     $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
      if ($result === FALSE) { }

     echo $result ;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents
Replace header definitions.

Comment: @eustatos good anser for `x-www-form-urlencoded` but not JSON

Comment: I edited your question to add ........, ''''''''' and capital letters. I recommend using them next time, it makes your question easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your payload to json...

```
$data = json_encode( array(
  'user' => 'xxx',
  'pass' => 'xxx',
  'code' => 'xxx'
) );
```

and to remove `\r\n` from your content type

```
"Content-type: application/json"
```

Comment: If this doesn't work you may need to use CURL.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920291/post-request-with-json-body

Comment: Try removing the `\r\n` from your content type too.